# Example of a monic in $\mathbf{Top}$ that is not regular

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

From [Leinster - Basic Category Theory - p136 5.2.25 (c)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.09375)

The question is to find a monic in $\mathbf{Top}$ which is not regular.

Some background, and my progress so far:

The monics $m: A \rightarrow B$ in $\mathbf{Top}$ are injections. So if we consider the restriction of $B$ to the image of $m$, and equip it with the subspace topology, then we have a homeomorphism from $A$ onto $m[A]$, or an embedding of $A$.   Now consider two maps $f,g: B \rightarrow \{0,1\}$, where {0,1} has the indiscrete topology, $f$ maps everything to $1$ and $g$ maps the elements of $m[A]$ to $1$. Then the equalizer $fm=gm$ represents the subspace embeddings. Specifically, the equalizer is a set consisting of all embeddings of $X$ for all $X \subseteq A$. The *regular* monics are those where an equalizer exists, and where an equalizer exists in $\mathbf{Top}$, it is the subspace embeddings as described. This is because equalizers are a limit, and limits are unique up to isomorphism.

Now I am after a monic that is **not** regular. So I suppose this is a monic that does not admit an equalizer with some $f \neq g$, as above. The only example I can think of are monics $m$ as above where $B$ has the indiscrete topology. Then $f$ and $g$ are essentially the same map, they both map everything to 1. As far as I can see, if $B$ has any more than one open set, then an equalizer should exist. Can someone please suggest where I have gone wrong, and/or an alternative answer?

Comment: You are aware that all regular monos in top are the inclusion of a subspace. You are also aware that all injections are monos. So simply find an injection between spaces which is not the inclusion of a subspace. In particular, you can find some space $X$ and some set $V \subseteq X$, and equip $V$ with a strictly finer topology than the subspace topology.